# Samsung Galaxy S Plus formatted itself

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-plus

The past couple of days my Galaxy S Plus started lagging, and today all of sudden it got stuck. When I restarted it the phone was completely wiped, had no apps, no contacts, nothing.  Now when I try installing any app it just says "Downloading" but nothing happens - nothing gets installed. I have no idea what is happening. Could some one tell me what I should do?

It was on stock firmware when is locked up. I tried a soft reset; after clicking "Erase everything" nothing happens, it just shows the factory reset title on top and blank screen below.

[image]
[image]

I also tried a hard reset without success. I took out the battery then held home volume up and power together while powering it on, but it just shows on screen "Ram Dump mode" and some other stuff. No menu shows up.
[image]

Comment: Just a thought: have you explored the possibility of getting `adb` access to the device in recovery mode? You might be able to reflash the device entirely, flashing CWM and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_Plus/GT-I9001 
This might help, it might not. do let us know.

Comment: Please try to avoid [answering with only a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/164138). If the link is broken your answer becomes useless. It is better to include the essential parts of the document you are referring to in your answer directly and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your phone's internal memory may be physically damaged or suffering from severe corruption (such as many bad blocks).  If that's the case, it may be mounting the system as read only which would prevent you from downloading and installing apps.  If it is still under warranty, you should probably exchange it for a new one.

Comment: just bought it a month ago so its still under warranty, but bought it from another country, they did say it had international warranty but lets c, will have to get the bill shipped from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you visited malicious web page or your phone received malicious text message containing the factory reset maintenance code which doesn't ask for confirmation. http://www.androidcentral.com/major-security-vulnerability-samsung-phones-could-trigger-factory-reset-web-browser is the first link which I find quickly googling for it.

Comment: That wouldn't explain the subsequent problems with app installation, etc.